# Find the edge domination number of the graph of Fig. $1-14.$

Tags: graph-theory

$A$ set $F$ of edges in a graph $G (V, E)$ is a dominating edge set if every edge not in $F$ has a vertex in common with an edge in $F$. The edge domination number is the number of edges in a minimum edge domination set. Find the edge domination number of the graph of Fig. $1$-$14.$ [image: Fig. 1-14]!]

I've been thinking $\{7,4\}$ and $\{2,6\}$ is the minimum edge domination set, but $\{7,4\}$ and $\{2, 1\}$ is also possible as all the vertices are connected. I'm not sure how to think of this problem or if there's another way to think of it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3010829/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: @mrtaurho fixed :)

Comment: Good, good. Now please try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for further edits aswell as for new questions and answers in order to fulfill the appropiate standards of MSE :)